# Delphi 7 переименование файлов

Tags: delphi

Как правильно переименовать Юнит1.пас и файл формы?
суть проблемы в том что при добавлении формы из одного проекта в другой обнаруживается совпадение по именам и среда не сохраняет,что вполне понятно..

так-же зачастую попадаюсь на ошибку в

```
unit L2;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, MPlayer;
type
  TL2 = class(TForm)
// Перечень компонентов и процедур присутствующих в программе
 private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  L2: TL2; //Здесь ошибка Identifier redeclared: 'L2'
 a,b:Integer; //переменные для вычесления площади фигур
 x,y:Integer;  // Переменные целого типа которые отвечают за координаты
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
```

далее процедуры!

Добавлю так-же файл собственно проекта:

```
program Project1;
uses
  Forms,
  L2 in 'L2.pas' {L2};
{$R *.res}
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.Title := 'Лаба №2';
  Application.CreateForm(TL2,L2);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открыть проект с нужной формой, переименовать её, выбрать пункт "Save As" и сохранить как нужно, куда нужно и с нужным именем.

Answer (score 1):

По второй проблеме - не надо называть юнит (модуль) и форму в этом юните одинаковыми названиями (идентификаторами). 
Если это так "жизненно" важно, назовите их, например, так Unit_L2 и Form_L2 соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

L2.pas и L2.dfm
если конечно это - содержимое Вашего unit1.